# Exception when compiling my app in android studio

Tags: android-studio, exception

```
Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_228" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Elizabeth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:178)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried to do what it's suggested in the exception by trying to stop your antivirus ?

Comment: Windows defender?

Comment: I don't use antivirus

Comment: did you check that the appt is closed in the task manager as sometimes you don't see but it's working in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not use antivirus, I just stopped the compilation of the app and closed android studio from the **task manager**. Then I reopened the project and started compiling the app, after a few minutes everything went well.